# Do Battlefield 4 and its expansions have different stories?

Tags: battlefield-4

I finished the single player campaign of Battlefield 4. Later I found out that it has expansions.

Now my question is if Battlefield 4 and its expansions have different story lines or not?

Answer (score 1):

The expansions only introduce new multiplayer content. This includes maps (usually 4 per expansion), related assignments, vehicles, weapons, etc.

The single player campaign receives no updates from expansions.

Comment: As an afterthought: Even the bug in the mission where swimming is involved was still affecting me when I played the campaign recently, even though reports of it go back to 2015 and I own all expansions.